# Java command line compile

Tags: java, command-line, compilation, terminal

I recently finished a programming assignment using Netbeans and Java. When I run the program in Netbeans everything runs perfect. My issue comes when I try and run it from the terminal. I run javac with all my .java files and it produces a .class file for each one. Then when I try to run the executable it errors out on me.

```
ls
Board.java          KenKenPuzzleSolver.java 
Solver.java         Cage.java 
Size.java           Values.java

javac KenKenPuzzleSolver.java Board.java Cage.java Size.java Solver.java Values.java

ls
Board.class         Size.class
Board.java          Size.java
Cage.class          Solver.class
Cage.java           Solver.java
KenKenPuzzleSolver.class    Values.class
KenKenPuzzleSolver.java     Values.java

java KenKenPuzzleSolver
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: KenKenPuzzleSolver (wrong name: kenkenpuzzlesolver/KenKenPuzzleSolver)
```

Also, when the program is run from the terminal it should take in an input file and the name of an output file i.e. "java KenKenPuzzleSolver input.txt output.txt", and I am not quite sure how to do this.

Comment: Read more about the role of `CLASSPATH` and the arguments to your `static main` method.

Comment: for more info about `javac` enter `man javac`. read it, and it well probably solve your problem.

Comment: You got a package problem, it seems that your KenKenPuzzleSolver is actually kenkenpuzzlesolver.KenKenPuzzleSolver (inside the package kenkenpuzzlesolver) check your package declaration, if it is so, you need to come one directory behind and execute `java kenkenpuzzlesolver.KenKenPuzzleSolver`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you generate an executable with netbeans? You don't have to compile your code every time.

`input.txt` and `output.txt` are called arguments. They will be stored in the `String[] args` array in you `main` function.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide the classpath parameter.

Use `javac -cp YOURCLASSPATH KenKenPuzzleSolver`

Answer (score 0):

The class that you are running should be public and should have the class name same as your file name.  It seems like your file name is "KenKenPuzzleSolver"  but your class name seems to be "KenkenPuzzleSolver"  ( Observe the lowercase ken ).   correct that and recompile and re run.

Answer (score 0):

You must have messed with cases, from error its obvious instead of `KenKenPuzzleSolver` you have named your class as `kenkenpuzzlesolver`in `KenKenPuzzleSolver.java`.